# When I'm making request to http page from my android app, mobile keyword is added to url

Tags: java, android, http, url

I'm writing android app, and want to make http request to web page.
I'm using HttpUrlConnection in order to make connection.

if I want to make request for example to url http://xxxxx.com, the android changed it
to url http://mobile.xxxxx.com.

I don't want to do a http request with mobile keyword in url.

Any possibility to remove that mobile keyword from URL?
Thanks in advance

Comment: its remote webserver detects your header and redirects you to mobile domain, try faking http headers

Comment: can I somehow remove that header? because I checked the headers on my URL connection headers, and it is empty. android system adds this?

Comment: Thanks Jigar Joshi, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally remote web server whens ees the headers related to mobile platform, they redirect user to mobile version of app for better experience, so to solve it try faking http headers